# Proof that the equation $3^x=3+x$ has a solution in the interval $(0,1)$

Tags: analysis

Proof that the equation  $3^x=3+x$ has a solution in the interval $(0,1)$ and the equation  $e^{-x} = sin(\frac{π}{2}x)$ has a solution in the interval.

I thought about it, and still cannot find where to start.

Any ideas?, Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the interval is $(0,1)$? Because $3^x=3+x$ doesn't have a solution in that interval.

Comment: Wrong. $3^x=3+x$ has exactly two real solutions $x\approx -2.96$, $x\approx 1.335$. [WolframAlpha says this.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%5Ex%3D3%2Bx)

Answer (score 0):

The first is false.  The positive root is about $1.335$.  For the second, use the intermediate value theorem.  Evaluate the two functions at the end points of the interval, note that they are continuous, and therefore must cross.

Answer (score 0):

$3^x=3+x$ has exactly two real solutions $x\approx -2.96$, $x\approx 1.335$. [WolframAlpha says this.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%5Ex%3D3%2Bx) There are no solutions when $x\in (0,1)$.

$e^{-x}=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot x)$ has a real solution when $x\in (0,1)$. To prove it, let $f(x)=e^{-x}-\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot x)$. $f(0)=1$, $f(1)=\frac{1}{e}-1=\frac{1-e}{e}<0$, $f(x)$ is continuous when $x\in[0,1]$, therefore by the intermediate value theorem $f(x)=a$ for all $a\in \left(\frac{1-e}{e},1\right)$ has a solution when $x\in(0,1)$, let $a=0$.